# How can i leave the margin between the card with CSS when i resize the page ? i use flex

Tags: html, css

How can I leave the margin between the card with CSS when I resize the page? I use flex
I want to scroll the card with overflow-x but doesn't work I try with `overflow-x` but not work how I think
how can I scroll horizonataly with overflow?
How can I leave the margin between the card with CSS when I resize the page? I use flex
I want to scroll the card with overflow-x but doesn't work I try with overflow-x but not work how I think
how can I scroll horizonataly with overflow?

[image]

[image]

```html
<div class="section-footer">

    <div class="container-fluid center-space">
        <div class="row  overflow_x">
            <div class="col-3">
                <ul>

                    <li><h6>Scopri Deliveroo</h6></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Chi siamo</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Pressroom</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Il nostro blog</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Programmazione</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Design</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Lavora con noi</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Diventa nostro partner</a></li>
    
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="col-3">
                
                <ul>

                    <li><h6>Note legali</h6></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Termini e condizioni</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Informativa sulla privacy</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Cookies</a></li>
    
                </ul>
                
            </div>
            <div class="col-3">

                <ul>

                    <li><h6>Aiuto</h6></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Contatti</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">FAQ</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Tipi di cucina</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Mappa del sito</a></li>
    
                </ul>
                
            </div>
            <div class="col-3">

                <ul>

                    <li><h6>Porta Deliveroo con te</h6></li>
                    <li><img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcR9SCcWWyYL-qlyts-92R7oxQuJseBK3qeQzH4AUNNKW4qKadazLxDtjcAIZgQwfXB2ybw&usqp=CAU" alt=""></li>
                    <li><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/5f/Google_Play_Store_badge_IT.svg/640px-Google_Play_Store_badge_IT.svg.png" alt=""></li>
                    
    
                </ul>
                
            </div>
            
        </div>
        <div class="bottom-footer d-flex justify-content-between">
            <div>
                <i class="fab fa-facebook "></i>
                <i class="fab fa-twitter"></i>
                <i class="fab fa-instagram"></i>

            </div>
            <div>
                <small>© 2021 Deliveroo</small>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</template>

<script>
export default {

}
</script>

<style lang="scss" scoped>

$color-li : white;
.section-footer{
    overflow-x:hidden;
    background-color: #2e3333;
    width: 100%;
    height: 22rem;
    .overflow_x{
        overflow-x: auto;     
    }
    
    ul{
        min-width:10rem;
        width: 13rem;
        border-radius: 5px;
        margin: 2rem 0;
        background-color: #434848;
        padding: 15px;
        height: 80%;
        li{
            display:block;
            color:$color-li;
            list-style: none;
           
            h6{
                font-size: 90%;
            }
            a{
                text-decoration: none;
                color:$color-li;
                font-size: 70%;
                font-weight: bold;

            }
            a:hover{
                color:teal;
            }
            img{
                width:60%;
                height: 90%;
                border-radius:10px;
                margin: 5px 0;
                cursor: pointer;
            }
        }
    }


    .bottom-footer{
        width: 100%;
        padding: 0 15px;
        i{
            color:$color-li;
            margin: 0.3rem;
            cursor:pointer;
        }
        i:hover{
            color:teal;

        }
        small{
            color:$color-li;
            color: #4f6f85;
            font-size: 0.7rem;
        }
        
    }
}


</style>
<style>
.center-space{
    width:80%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Please add the code.

Comment: Add code for more details

Answer (score 0):

Use media query

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  body {
    background-color: lightblue;
  }
}
```

You can change margin padding of tag with media query
It work like if condition

Answer (score 0):

WHEN YOU RE-SIZE THE PAGE USE KEYBOARD ARROW'S TO SCROLL RIGHT OR LEFT. HOPE THIS WILL BE USEFULL.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>

/*DEFAULT*/
body{
margin:0;
overflow-x:hidden;
}
li{
list-style:none;
}
a{
text-decoration:none;
color:rgba(255,255,255,.5);
}
* {
box-sizing: border-box;
}

.column {
float: left;
width: 25%;
}

.row {margin: 0 -5px;}

.row:after {
content: "";
display: table;
clear: both;
}

.card {
padding: 16px;
height:22rem;
background-color:#434848;
}

.card img{
width:200px;
height:90%;
}

.card h6{
color:#fff;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 900px) {
.column {
min-width: 100%;
display: block;
margin-bottom: 20px;
padding:0px 10px;
box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.row{
display:flex;
align-items:left;
justify-content: left;
overflow-x:auto;
scrollbar-width:none;
scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="row">
<div class="column">
<div class="card">
<ul>

<li><h6>Scopri Deliveroo</h6></li>
<li><a href="#">Chi siamo</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Pressroom</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Il nostro blog</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Programmazione</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Design</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Lavora con noi</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Diventa nostro partner</a></li>

</ul>
</div>
</div>

<div class="column">
<div class="card">
<ul>

<li><h6>Note legali</h6></li>
<li><a href="#">Termini e condizioni</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Informativa sulla privacy</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Cookies</a></li>

</ul>
</div>
</div>

<div class="column">
<div class="card">
<ul>

<li><h6>Aiuto</h6></li>
<li><a href="#">Contatti</a></li>
<li><a href="#">FAQ</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Tipi di cucina</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Mappa del sito</a></li>

</ul>
</div>
</div>
<div class="column">
<div class="card">
<ul>

<li><h6>Porta Deliveroo con te</h6></li>
<li><img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcR9SCcWWyYL-qlyts-92R7oxQuJseBK3qeQzH4AUNNKW4qKadazLxDtjcAIZgQwfXB2ybw&usqp=CAU" alt=""></li>
<li><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/5f/Google_Play_Store_badge_IT.svg/640px-Google_Play_Store_badge_IT.svg.png" alt=""></li>

</ul>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```